# Converting a string to a hash integer

Tags: java

I have to convert a string of length k with 4 possible characters - {A, C, G, T} - into an integer between 0 and 4^k. The advice is to convert the {A, C, G, T} into {0, 1, 2, 3} respectively, but I do not know how to convert those numbers into a number between 0 and 4^k.
For example, if the string "ACT" is given, I have to convert that to a number between 0 and 64.

Comment: Maybe you want to look at a different numerical type. Otherwise length 15 will already be the maximum length before the integer overflows.

Comment: We have been told to limit k to be between 2 and 6, sorry I forgot to include that.

Comment: Well I have to treat the ACGT as if they are base 4, with A as 0 and T as 3, and then somehow convert those base 4 to an integer between 0 and 4^k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```java
char[] chars=yourString.toCharArray();
int result=0;
for(char c:chars){
    result*=4;
    switch(c){
        case 'A':
            result+=0;
            break;
        case 'C':
            result+=1;
            break;
        case 'G':
             result+=2;
             break;
        case 'T':
             result+=3;
             break;
    }
}
```

This takes every character and adds a value from 0 to 3 to the result (depending on the character).

After that, the value is multiplied with 4 in order to leace space for the next value.

Note that this is not hashing because it can be reversed easily.

A one-line-version of the code would be:

```java
Integer.parseInt(yourString.replace('A','0').replace('C','1').replace('G','2').replace('T','3'),4);
```

This replaces A/C/G/T to 0/1/2/3 and reads it as a base 4 number.

---

You can also get the original String from the converted int:

```java
int intVal;//whatever it is
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
while(intVal!=0){
    switch(intVal%4){
        case 0:
            sb.append('A');
            break;
        case 1:
            sb.append('C');
            break;
        case 2:
            sb.append('G');
            break;
        case 3:
            sb.append('T');
            break;
    }
    intVal=intVal/4;
}
String result=intVal.reverse().toString();
```

This gets each digit one after another and adds the corresponding value to the `StringBuilder`. Because it starts with the last digit, a reversal is needed.

It is also possible to create a one-liner for this:

```java
Integer.toString(intVal,4).replace('0','A').replace('1',C').replace('2','G').replace('3','T');
```

---

Note that you might want to use `long`/`BigInteger` for longer sequences as you would reach the integer limit for those.

Since `int` has 32 bits of data, you could use sequences up to 16 characters. With `long`, you could have sequences up to 32 characters and with `BigInteger`, you would likely reach the memory limit of JVM with your sequence string or the `char[]` used in the calculation before the limit of `BigInteger` becomes a problem (the limit of `BigInteger` is 2 to the power of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`).

Comment: Would mean that A, AA, AAA etc are all mapped to the same value (just an example, there are probably more collisions)

Comment: @thinkgruen: The question describes "a string of length k" rather than "a string of length up to k". If it's "up to k" then there are more than 4^k possibilities.

Comment: Yes, there are collisions for different lengths (just with `A`s, though) but each String with the same length has a unique corresponding value.

Comment: If there are different lengths and you want unique/reversable values, you could also use the length at the beginning of the number or use `5` as a base and start with `1`.

Comment: But I don't think this is much of a problem with DNA sequences.

Comment: Will this not leave "gaps"? I am attempting to get these values to use them for indexes within an array, will this solution not only return multiples of 4?

Comment: I made a small mistake but I fixed it now. `A=0,C=1,G=2,T=3,CA=4,CB=5,...` It basically is a numeric system with base 4 (decimal...base 10, binary...base 2, hexadecimal...base 16) but not with `0123` but with `ACGT`.

Comment: I think you should only talk about the one line version but explain it properly

Comment: Didn't you mean `Integer.parseInt` instead of `Integer.toString`?

Comment: For newer versions of Java, this code would benefit a lot from [Switch Expressions](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/361)

Comment: It would but the OP did not state the java version he is using so I didn't use switch expressions for this. Another way would be to omit the `break`s and increment `result` with `1` each time.

Comment: The issue is, in the example you gave with A=0 and CA=4, if the string is for example 3 letters long, then AAA should = 0 and AAC = 1, for example.

Comment: I know, this is the same thing with 00001 and 1. If you want to fix this, you could use `1` as the initial value so you have a padding (this would take a single bit).

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution! I implemented something very similar and it works. My only issue is now, how would I go about determining which string belongs to which int index? Like how would I be able to reverse it and be able to tell that int 0 belongs to AA, int 1 belongs to AC, etc.

Comment: @MatthewKeys You can reverse with `Integer.toString` with radix 4 and then replace `0` back to `A` etc. (pad with additional `0` according to `k` first)

Comment: I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer that matches what you ask for is:

```
dna.chars().map(x -> "ACGT".indexOf((char)x)).reduce((acc, x) -> acc << 2 | x).getAsInt();
```

This first maps each character ACGT to the numeric value that you want (which takes 2 bits to hold) and reduces that to an integer by stringing these 2-bit values together. This is a base-4 encoding.

How to use:

```
String dna = "ACT";
int encoded = dna.chars().map(x -> "ACGT".indexOf((char)x)).reduce((acc, x) -> acc << 2 | x).getAsInt();
System.out.println("Encoded " + encoded);
```

If you want to encode any length of DNA string this way, you can use `BigInteger`:

```
String dna = "ACTGGTTAACATTCTCTAG";
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
dna.chars().forEachOrdered(x -> b.append((char)('0' + "ACGT".indexOf((char)x))));
BigInteger encoded = new BigInteger(b.toString(), 4);
```